# How to load Doubleclick ads along side dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads, dynamic-content, google-dfp

I have been trying to get Doubleclick ad tags to load with my dynamic content. I have a website which loads more content as you scroll down rather than having to go to the next page, back a page, etc. However I have been unsuccessful in getting my ads which I have on every 2nd to 3rd page to load.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

*edit*

Code in the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/XXX/XXX', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-XXX-0').addService(googletag.pubads());

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
```

I have also tried removing "enableSingleRequest" however that didn't seem to help.

Ad code in body:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-XXX-0' style='width:300px; height:250px;'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-XXX-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `However I have been unsuccessful in getting my ads which I have on every 2nd to 3rd page to load.` - Can we see what you have tried already?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything of use, just simply calling the javascript by function. I was hoping someone else may have the solution, I couldn't find anything on google about it. I also tried calling "googletag.enableServices();" when the new content is appended however that didn't work.

Comment: Do the ads work if you put them on the initial page load?

Comment: They do work without any issues when being initially loaded.

Comment: Then your issue lies with how you're trying to display them during the ajax loading. Can we see the code for this?

Comment: Make sure you are not using enable single request... I think that may stop it from working... the refresh method is probably what you need... would need to see code.

Comment: I have updated my question with the current code I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out.

jQuery.load was stripping the script tags from my html after loading it and DFP didn't like that. I ended up using https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js and it solved all the issue.